# Python not sorting Unicode correctly

Tags: python

```
data = [unicode('č', "cp1250"),
        unicode('d', "cp1250"),
        unicode('a', "cp1250")]

data.sort(key=unicode.lower) 

for x in range(0,len(data)):
    print data[x].encode("cp1250")
```

and I get:

```
a
d
č
```

It should be:

```
a
č
d
```

Slovenia Alphabet goes like: a b c č d e f g.....

I'm using WIN XP(Active code page: 852 - Slovenia). Can you help me?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097908/how-do-i-sort-alphabetically-in-python

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem an now have a working program:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'slovenian')
data = ['č', 'ab', 'aa', 'a', 'd', 'ć', 'B', 'c']
data.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)
print "Sorted..."
for x in range(0,len(data)):
    print data[x]
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it doesn't work for me on Python 2.7.3. I get: a ć č aa ab B c d

Answer (score 1):

See the `locale` module for language-aware sorting. Especially the `strcoll` and `strxfrm` functions.