# case-insensitive list sorting, without lowercasing the result?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, case-insensitive

I have a list of strings like this:

```
['Aden', 'abel']
```

I want to sort the items, case-insensitive.
So I want to get:

```
['abel', 'Aden']
```

But I get the opposite with `sorted()` or `list.sort()`, because uppercase appears before lowercase.

How can I ignore the case? I've seen solutions which involves lowercasing all list items, but I don't want to change the case of the list items.

Comment: This tutorial is very helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

Answer (score 324, accepted):

In Python 3.3+ there is the [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) method that's specifically designed for caseless matching:

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=str.casefold)
```

In Python 2 use `lower()`:

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda s: s.lower())
```

It works for both normal and unicode strings, since they both have a `lower` method.

In Python 2 it works for a mix of normal and unicode strings, since values of the two types can be compared with each other. Python 3 doesn't work like that, though: you can't compare a byte string and a unicode string, so in Python 3 you should do the sane thing and only sort lists of one type of string.

```
>>> lst = ['Aden', u'abe1']
>>> sorted(lst)
['Aden', u'abe1']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda s: s.lower())
[u'abe1', 'Aden']
```

Comment: One can avoid the lambda function roundtrip by __(Python 3)__ using the general [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) function as `sorted(lst, key=str.lower)` or __(Python 2)__ using the [`lower` method of the `string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) as `sorted(lst, key=string.lower)`. One can also use `str.lower` for strings in Python 2, but would then have to use `unicode.lower` for `unicode` objects, whereas `string.lower` accepts both (which, as you put it, is probably not really a "sane" mode of operation, though).

Comment: This would not work for a list like ['Z', 'B', 'a', 'b', 'A'], which sorts to ['a', 'A', 'B', 'b', 'Z']. The capital 'B' appears before the lowercase 'b' because Python's sort() and sorted() preserve the original order when strings match. In this case the capital 'B' is considered to match the lowercase 'b' when using casefold. This always happens if you convert case in order to compare: sorted(spam, key=str.lower) or sorted(spam, key=str.upper) or sorted(spam, key=str.casefold).

Comment: Try this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098160/10668287. It will sort ['Aden', 'aden'] correctly as ['aden', 'Aden'].

Comment: Why does `sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=str.casefold)` when `str` in `str.casefold` is not defined?

Answer (score 52):

```
>>> x = ['Aden', 'abel']
>>> sorted(x, key=str.lower) # Or unicode.lower if all items are unicode
['abel', 'Aden']
```

In Python 3 `str` is unicode but in Python 2 you can use this more general approach which works for both `str` and `unicode`:

```
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda s: s.lower())
['abel', 'Aden']
```

Comment: Thank you. I know I should have mentioned this before, but I've heard there's a problem with using this method on a unicode string (Py2). Do you know anything about that?

Comment: They are all unicode. Thanks! One more question, how to do it on a list like this: `[['Aden'], ['abel']]`

Comment: Does each list only have one item? If so just modify it a bit to: `sorted(x,key=lambda i:i[0].lower())`

Comment: Well, it might have some other stuff as well, which should not be used for sorting though.

Comment: Nevermind, it appears i was wrong, the sorting does work for a mix of both string and unicode, i was confused with a previous question where tuples were also included in the sort.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try this to sort the list in-place:

```
>>> x = ['Aden', 'abel']
>>> x.sort(key=lambda y: y.lower())
>>> x
['abel', 'Aden']
```

Answer (score 9):

This works in Python 3 and does not involves lowercasing the result (!).

```
values.sort(key=str.lower)
```

Comment: howto sorting: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions        
list.sort: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Answer (score 4):

In python3 you can use

```
list1.sort(key=lambda x: x.lower()) #Case In-sensitive             
list1.sort() #Case Sensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way for Python 3.3:

```
 def sortCaseIns(lst):
    lst2 = [[x for x in range(0, 2)] for y in range(0, len(lst))]
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        lst2[i][0] = lst[i].lower()
        lst2[i][1] = lst[i]
    lst2.sort()
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        lst[i] = lst2[i][1]
```

Then you just can call this function:

```
sortCaseIns(yourListToSort)
```

Comment: The biggest issue with this solution is that it violates the rule of using the built-in tested tooling for a home grown solution. It is an interesting response though, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Case-insensitive sort, sorting the string *in place*, in Python 2 OR 3 (tested in Python 2.7.17 and Python 3.6.9):

```
>>> x = ["aa", "A", "bb", "B", "cc", "C"]
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
>>> x.sort(key=str.lower)           # <===== there it is!
>>> x
['A', 'aa', 'B', 'bb', 'C', 'cc']
```

The key is `key=str.lower`. Here's what those commands look like with just the commands, for easy copy-pasting so you can test them:

```
x = ["aa", "A", "bb", "B", "cc", "C"]
x.sort()
x
x.sort(key=str.lower)
x
```

Note that if your strings are unicode strings, however (like `u'some string'`), then in Python 2 only (NOT in Python 3 in this case) the above `x.sort(key=str.lower)` command will fail and output the following error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

If you get this error, then either upgrade to Python 3 where they handle unicode sorting, or convert your unicode strings to ASCII strings first, using a list comprehension, like this:

```
# for Python2, ensure all elements are ASCII (NOT unicode) strings first
x = [str(element) for element in x]  
# for Python2, this sort will only work on ASCII (NOT unicode) strings
x.sort(key=str.lower)
```

### References:

1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort
2. [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols/13073070#13073070)
3. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

**Python3:**

Sorting is discussed in other answers but here is what is going on behind the scenes with the sort options.

Say we would like to sort the following list case-insensitive we can use **'key='**:

```
strs = ['aa', 'BB', 'zz', 'CC']
strs_sorted = sorted(strs,key=str.lower)
print(strs_sorted)
 ['aa', 'BB', 'CC', 'zz']
```

**What is happening here ?**

The key is telling the sort to use 'proxy values. **'Key='** transforms each element before comparison. The key function takes in 1 value and returns 1 value, and the returned "proxy" value is used for the comparisons within the sort.

[image: proxy sorting example]

Hence we are employing **'.lower'** to make all of our proxy values all lowercase which eliminates the case differences and returns the list in order by lowercase essentially.

**str.lower vs str.casefold**

As mentioned in other posts you can also use **"casefold()"** as the key or anything (for example "len" to sort by char length).  The casefold() method is an aggressive lower() method which converts strings to case folded strings for caseless matching.

```
sorted(strs,key=str.casefold)
```

**What about creating my own sort function?**

Generally speaking, it is always best to use the built-in functions for sorting unless there is an extreme need not to. The build-in functions have been unit tested and will most likely the most reliable.

**Python2:**

Similar principle,

```
sorted_list = sorted(strs, key=lambda s: s.lower())
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
def cSort(inlist, minisort=True):
    sortlist = []
    newlist = []
    sortdict = {}
    for entry in inlist:
        try:
            lentry = entry.lower()
        except AttributeError:
            sortlist.append(lentry)
        else:
            try:
                sortdict[lentry].append(entry)
            except KeyError:
                sortdict[lentry] = [entry]
                sortlist.append(lentry)

    sortlist.sort()
    for entry in sortlist:
        try:
            thislist = sortdict[entry]
            if minisort: thislist.sort()
            newlist = newlist + thislist
        except KeyError:
            newlist.append(entry)
    return newlist
```

---

```
lst = ['Aden', 'abel']
print cSort(lst)
```

Output

`['abel', 'Aden']`

Comment: This solution is overkill and unreadable when a one-liner suffices. This might be more acceptable in a language other than Python.

Comment: The biggest issue with this solution is that it violates the rule of using the built-in tested tooling for a home grown solution. It is an interesting response though, I'll give you that.