# py3k: case-insensitive list sorting - With or WIthout lambda?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, python-3.x, case-insensitive

In:

[case-insensitive list sorting, without lowercasing the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269701/case-insensitive-list-sorting-without-lowercasing-the-result)

I've seen two solutions:
(Let;s assume input is list of utf-8 strings, e.g. `['z1', 'A1', 'a0', 'bC']`)

- Without lambda: `L.sort(key = str.lower);`
- With lambda: `L.sort(key = lambda s: s.lower());`

What are differences?
Which is better or more "pythonic"?

(As I tagged question is about `python-3.x`. All comments related to behaviour specific to python 2 are welcome, but please make note)

Comment: The first one. Because simple is better than complex (and it is much faster)

Comment: @JBernardo -- make that an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: As a general note, unless a lambda is very, very concise (and more concise than any alternative), it's generally the wrong course of action. Python has functions you can pass around as ordinary variables, so lambdas are not actually that useful.

Comment: Reminds me of various comments about regular expressions. In [Reactive Programming with JavaScript](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1783558555/) I explained why I considered them one of JavaScript's (write-only) bad parts, and deliberately ported a model with central use of regular expressions was superceded by programmed that accomplished a similar effect, but written in e.g. English, not runes and line noise.

Answer (score 4):

`str.lower` is an unbound method of the `str` type, `lambda s: s.lower()` is an anonymous function. The end effect is the same: for each element in `L`, the `key` callable is called, passing in the element.

The *effects* could be different if you are not sorting strings. The `str.lower` method only works with strings, while the anonymous lambda function will work with anything that has a `.lower()` method; use this when you have a mixture of `bytes` and `str`, for example.

I prefer the first version, it's shorter and a little faster. Moreover, it'll throw an error if my values are not strings, which is *usually* what you want.

Comment: To be fair, it has different semantics if `s` is not a string (but an unary `lower` method). But that's unlikely, probably unexpected, and if it's unexpected the `str.lower` version is better because it throws an error instead of silently working. Exception: Unicode strings in Python 2. I'm not really sure what happens then.

Comment: @delnan: yeah, that is an important difference. Expanded.

Comment: @delnan -- could you make an answer from your comment about differences in semantics, so I could select it as solution?

Comment: @delnan: passing a `unicode` string to `str.lower` doesn't work, it throws an error. Same for `bytes` strings in python 3.x.

Comment: Of course if someone has a custom string class that's overridden `lower`, then `str.lower` could give misleading results. Another option which is similar to `lambda s: s.lower()` is to borrow from the operator module and provide `key=methodcaller('lower')`

Answer (score 2):

A 3rd option is `methodcaller` from the `operator` module.

```
from operator import methodcaller
L.sort(key=methodcaller('lower'))
```

It's equivalent to the `lambda` option in what it does, but depending on taste, is nice and readable and being from the operator module, fairly nippy. The `str.lower` will break if the object is a `unicode` string (and vice-versa).

Comment: Are you sure that `str.lower` will break on `unicode`? The question is about Python3k, which I thought is better prepared for `utf-8` than py2k.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: I am sure, `str.lower` with a `unicode` value in python 2, or a `bytes` value in python 3, throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: So `python-3.x` works with `unicode` (but not with `bytes`). Thanks for ensuring !

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki Your mention of UTF-8 tells me you should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Nice post. I will be useful for readers. Many ways of encoding Unicode (utf-8/16/32, big/logendian, with or without BOM...), are why I've narrowed my question to `utf-8`. This reminds me very nice [subchapter 4.2 Unicode of Dive into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html)