# How to alphabetize characters in a string, disregarding upper and lower case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It it possible to alphabetize the characters in a string, disregarding upper and lower case?  I need them to stay in the case they are in, so I can't use `.lower()` or `.upper()`, but I'd like for them to be arranged with the letter taking precedence, so the resulting string would be something like:

`"LMmqRRs"`

instead of

`"LMRRmqs"`

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269701/case-insensitive-list-sorting-without-lowercasing-the-result

Comment: Do you want the sort to be stable (i.e. "aA" would stay "aA" and "Aa" would stay "Aa") or do you want the cases to have a specific order, whether "aA" or "Aa"?

Comment: I'd rather have the uppercase come first for any given number of the same letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes sure capital letters go first:

```
s = 'mqRMRsL'
result = ''.join(sorted(s, key=lambda c:(c.lower(), c)))
# LMmqRRs
```

This doesn't:

```
s = 'mqRMRsL'
result = ''.join(sorted(s, key=str.lower))
# LmMqRRs
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a slight alteration to BlaXpirit solution to make the sort stable:

```
def alphabet_cmp(a, b):
    a_lower, b_lower = a.lower(), b.lower()
    if a_lower == b_lower:
        return cmp(a, b)
    else:
        return cmp(a_lower, b_lower)

x = 'ABcdCDab'
''.join(sorted(x, cmp=alphabet_cmp))
# 'AaBbCcDd'
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined`. `TypeError: 'cmp' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. See [**this**](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0#ordering-comparisons)

Comment: I don't know why cmp is an invalid keyword, the doc string for sorted in python 27 is "sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list" however your solution is more elegant and also stable and thus better than mine, I don't know why I didn't realize that when I quickly read your reply prior to posting, sorry

Comment: yes.. I didn't see that it was a python 3.0 thread I replied to... I just continue to make a fool of myself :)