# How to sort a string in python in order AaB instead of ABa

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string (to make a genotype for a punnetsquare).
My current implementation is:

```
unsorted_genotype = 'ABaB'
sorted_genotype = sorted(list(unsorted_genotype))
sorted_string = ''.join(sorted_genotype)
```

It outputs

```
'ABBa'
```

Though, I would want and expect:

```
'AaBB'
```

How can I change or fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [case-insensitive list sorting, without lowercasing the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269701/case-insensitive-list-sorting-without-lowercasing-the-result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a [sorting key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and use the sorting for tuples:

`[(1,1),(1,2)]`: Tuples are sorted by 1st element, on equality by 2nd to nth:

```
unsorted = 'ABaB'
s = sorted(unsorted, key= lambda x:(x.lower(),x))  
print(''.join(s))  # 'AaBB'
```

This ensures it is first sorted by the 'lower' character - grouping `a` and `A`  together and then by the actual character afterwards so they occure sorted as well: `ABaaAAaAaAAAB =>  AAAAAAAaaaaBB`

Readups:

- [Overview](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)
- [by key (part of the first link)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

A simple `key = str.lower` as suggested in the allegated dupe does not group `A` to `A` and `a` to `a` which would be nice to have for [Prunnet squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square)

---

If you had them rather stay in order of occurence then grouping lower- and uppercase together, you can use:

```
unsorted = 'ABaaAAaAaAAAB'
s = sorted(unsorted, key=str.lower)  # not by tuple, just by lower
print(''.join(s))
```

results in keeping the elements "in order":

```
AaaAAaAaAAABB   # instead of  AAAAAAAaaaaBB
```

and is described in [case-insensitive list sorting, without lowercasing the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269701/case-insensitive-list-sorting-without-lowercasing-the-result)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a key to the sorting function:

```
unsorted_genotype = 'ABaB'
sorted_genotype = sorted(unsorted_genotype, key=lambda x: x.lower())
''.join(sorted_genotype)

'AaBB'
```