# Finding intersection from list of list which has string as element

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following list of list, in which the inner list has 2 items in string format.

```
neighbor_list = [['Mo0',
  '[PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, -0.9210, 37.6032) [0.3333, -0.3333, 0.9458], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 1.8419, 37.6032) [0.3333, 0.6667, 0.9458], PeriodicSite: S (3.1903, 1.8419, 37.6032) [1.3333, 0.6667, 0.9458], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, -0.9210, 34.4734) [0.3333, -0.3333, 0.8671], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 1.8419, 34.4734) [0.3333, 0.6667, 0.8671], PeriodicSite: S (3.1903, 1.8419, 34.4734) [1.3333, 0.6667, 0.8671]]'],
 ['Mo1',
  '[PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, -0.9210, 12.7242) [0.3333, -0.3333, 0.3200], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 1.8419, 12.7242) [0.3333, 0.6667, 0.3200], PeriodicSite: S (3.1903, 1.8419, 12.7242) [1.3333, 0.6667, 0.3200], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, -0.9210, 9.5944) [0.3333, -0.3333, 0.2413], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 1.8419, 9.5944) [0.3333, 0.6667, 0.2413], PeriodicSite: S (3.1903, 1.8419, 9.5944) [1.3333, 0.6667, 0.2413]]'],
 ['Mo2',
  '[PeriodicSite: S (-1.5952, 0.9210, 30.1636) [-0.3333, 0.3333, 0.7587], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, 0.9210, 30.1636) [0.6667, 0.3333, 0.7587], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 3.6839, 30.1636) [0.6667, 1.3333, 0.7587], PeriodicSite: S (-1.5952, 0.9210, 27.0339) [-0.3333, 0.3333, 0.6800], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, 0.9210, 27.0339) [0.6667, 0.3333, 0.6800], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 3.6839, 27.0339) [0.6667, 1.3333, 0.6800]]'],
 ['Mo3',
  '[PeriodicSite: S (-1.5952, 0.9210, 5.2846) [-0.3333, 0.3333, 0.1329], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, 0.9210, 5.2846) [0.6667, 0.3333, 0.1329], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 3.6839, 5.2846) [0.6667, 1.3333, 0.1329], PeriodicSite: S (-1.5952, 0.9210, 2.1548) [-0.3333, 0.3333, 0.0542], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, 0.9210, 2.1548) [0.6667, 0.3333, 0.0542], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 3.6839, 2.1548) [0.6667, 1.3333, 0.0542]]']]
```

The first item in the inner list (say Mo0) is the center and all the S in second item are the surroundings. First I want to print the list of center atom addeded to the surroundings e.g. Mo0S6, Mo1S6, M02S6 and so on. Then I want to find if there are any common S between Mo0, Mo1, Mo2, Mo3 by using their coordinates, e.g. the coordinates for S in neighbor of Mo0 are :

```
S (1.5952, -0.9210, 37.6032) 
S (1.5952, -0.9210, 12.7242)
```

and so on.

I can get the center and surroundings by doing

```
for i in range(len(neighbor_list)):
    center = neighbor_list[i][0]
    surroundings = neighbor_list[i][1]
```

How can I sum the number of surroundings for each center atom and find the intersection between surroundings?

The final goal is to get the matrix in the following format

```
      Mo0S6  Mo1S6  Mo2S6  Mo3S6
Mo0S6    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
Mo1S6    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
Mo2S6    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
Mo3S6    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

All elements in the dataframe are 0 because there are no common S in this list.

Could anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should simplify your question, Make it more generic. It is hard to comprehend.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The structure of list itself is quiet complicated.

Comment: So they are common if the first two numbers in the tuple are equivalent? And how do you arrive at `6`? (e.g. Mo2S6)

Comment: Hi rahlf, they will be common only if all three coordinates are common. so , S (1.5952, -0.9210, 37.6032) 
S (1.5952, -0.9210, 12.7242)  are not common. Thanks.

Comment: this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841562/how-to-sort-a-string-in-python-in-order-aab-instead-of-aba#53841588) sorting the way Mo0S6, Mo1S6, M02S6 .

Comment: ['Mo2',
  '[PeriodicSite: S (-1.5952, 0.9210, 30.1636) [-0.3333, 0.3333, 0.7587], PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, 0.9210, 30.1636) [0.6667, 0.3333, 0.7587], 
  PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 3.6839, 30.1636) [0.6667, 1.3333, 0.7587], PeriodicSite: S (-1.5952, 0.9210, 27.0339) [-0.3333, 0.3333, 0.6800], 
  PeriodicSite: S (1.5952, 0.9210, 27.0339) [0.6667, 0.3333, 0.6800], PeriodicSite: S (0.0000, 3.6839, 27.0339) [0.6667, 1.3333, 0.6800]]'] contains 6 S atoms so its summed up as Mo2S6.

Comment: Hi Prashanta, Thanks for the link, but I am not looking for sorting. I need to count the number of S, surrounded to each Mo .

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your example, there exist **no** common points.

Comment: Yes you are right, there are no common points on the part of list I posted, so in this case returning 0 is even fine. My goal is to build a pandas dataframe with Mo0S6, Mo1S6, Mo2S6, Mo3S6 as header for row, columns and 1 if they have common S and 0 if they dont share any. Can you please extend it up to that point.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a method for identifying duplicates.

Comment: Thanks rahlf23, I will implement this and mark the answer.

Comment: Made some final modifications so that you don't have to resort to flattening the list of surroundings (accomplished in a similar manner using `stack()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean up your data using `ast.literal_eval` and `regex`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re, ast

surrounding = [[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in re.findall(r'\([ ,.\d-]+\)', i[1])] for i in neighbor_list]
centers = ['{0}S{1}'.format(i[0], len(s)) for i, s in zip(neighbor_list, surrounding)]

data = dict(zip(centers, surrounding))
```

Gives:

```
{'Mo0S6': [(1.5952, -0.921, 37.6032), (0.0, 1.8419, 37.6032), (3.1903, 1.8419, 37.6032), (1.5952, -0.921, 34.4734), (0.0, 1.8419, 34.4734), (3.1903, 1.8419, 34.4734)],
'Mo1S6': [(1.5952, -0.921, 12.7242), (0.0, 1.8419, 12.7242), (3.1903, 1.8419, 12.7242), (1.5952, -0.921, 9.5944), (0.0, 1.8419, 9.5944), (3.1903, 1.8419, 9.5944)],
'Mo2S6': [(-1.5952, 0.921, 30.1636), (1.5952, 0.921, 30.1636), (0.0, 3.6839, 30.1636), (-1.5952, 0.921, 27.0339), (1.5952, 0.921, 27.0339), (0.0, 3.6839, 27.0339)],
'Mo3S6': [(-1.5952, 0.921, 5.2846), (1.5952, 0.921, 5.2846), (0.0, 3.6839, 5.2846), (-1.5952, 0.921, 2.1548), (1.5952, 0.921, 2.1548), (0.0, 3.6839, 2.1548)]}
```

You can then generate a dataframe directly using `df = pd.Dataframe(data)`:

```
                       Mo0S6                      Mo1S6  \
0  (1.5952, -0.921, 37.6032)  (1.5952, -0.921, 12.7242)   
1     (0.0, 1.8419, 37.6032)     (0.0, 1.8419, 12.7242)   
2  (3.1903, 1.8419, 37.6032)  (3.1903, 1.8419, 12.7242)   
3  (1.5952, -0.921, 34.4734)   (1.5952, -0.921, 9.5944)   
4     (0.0, 1.8419, 34.4734)      (0.0, 1.8419, 9.5944)   
5  (3.1903, 1.8419, 34.4734)   (3.1903, 1.8419, 9.5944)   

                       Mo2S6                     Mo3S6  
0  (-1.5952, 0.921, 30.1636)  (-1.5952, 0.921, 5.2846)  
1   (1.5952, 0.921, 30.1636)   (1.5952, 0.921, 5.2846)  
2     (0.0, 3.6839, 30.1636)     (0.0, 3.6839, 5.2846)  
3  (-1.5952, 0.921, 27.0339)  (-1.5952, 0.921, 2.1548)  
4   (1.5952, 0.921, 27.0339)   (1.5952, 0.921, 2.1548)  
5     (0.0, 3.6839, 27.0339)     (0.0, 3.6839, 2.1548)
```

To find duplicates, we can simply use `stack()` and `duplicated(keep=False)`, where `keep=False` ensures that we return both duplicates and their associated centers:

```
df.stack()[df.stack().duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Yields:

```
Series([], dtype: object)
```

You can confirm this method works by intentionally creating a duplicate in your sample data.

Comment: I can get the duplicates, I want to store the len(duplicates) as a corresponding element in the matrix, can you please add that line to make it more clear.

Comment: Keep in mind that is not a code-writing service. Can you update the question with what you have tried? Look at `pd.transform()`

Answer (score 0):

Just parsing the strings without the need to import anything:

```
for item in neighbor_list:
    center=item[0]
    surroundings=item[1].split("PeriodicSite: S ")

    # remove extra brackets
    surroundings=surroundings[1:]
    surroundings[-1]=surroundings[-1][0:-1]

    print "%sS%d" % (center, len(surroundings))

    surroundings = [x.replace("("," ").replace(")"," ").replace("["," ").replace("]"," ").replace(","," ") for x in surroundings]
    surroundings = [x.split() for x in surroundings]

    for S in surroundings:
        print "S (%s,%s,%s)" % (S[0], S[1], S[2])
```

Gives:

```
Mo0S6
S (1.5952,-0.9210,37.6032)
S (0.0000,1.8419,37.6032)
S (3.1903,1.8419,37.6032)
S (1.5952,-0.9210,34.4734)
S (0.0000,1.8419,34.4734)
S (3.1903,1.8419,34.4734)
Mo1S6
S (1.5952,-0.9210,12.7242)
S (0.0000,1.8419,12.7242)
S (3.1903,1.8419,12.7242)
S (1.5952,-0.9210,9.5944)
S (0.0000,1.8419,9.5944)
S (3.1903,1.8419,9.5944)
Mo2S6
S (-1.5952,0.9210,30.1636)
S (1.5952,0.9210,30.1636)
S (0.0000,3.6839,30.1636)
S (-1.5952,0.9210,27.0339)
S (1.5952,0.9210,27.0339)
S (0.0000,3.6839,27.0339)
Mo3S6
S (-1.5952,0.9210,5.2846)
S (1.5952,0.9210,5.2846)
S (0.0000,3.6839,5.2846)
S (-1.5952,0.9210,2.1548)
S (1.5952,0.9210,2.1548)
S (0.0000,3.6839,2.1548
```

Comment: Thanks John, this is very helpful.