# How to sort a list alphabetically by treating same letters in different case as same in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If input is like `['z','t','Z','a','b','A','d']`,then after sorting I want to get output like `['a','A','b','d','t','z','Z']` or `['A','a','b','d','t','Z','z']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [case-insensitive list sorting, without lowercasing the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269701/case-insensitive-list-sorting-without-lowercasing-the-result)

Comment: Do you want order of upper-case and lowercase to be consistent, or stable based on the input list?

Comment: I've posted an answer that explicitly addresses both options.

Answer (score 4):

This will sort always upper-case letter first:

```
lst = ['z','t','Z','a','b','A','d']

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: 2*ord(k.lower()) + k.islower()))
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'a', 'b', 'd', 't', 'Z', 'z']
```

EDIT Thanks to @MadPhysicist in the comments, another variant:

```
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: (k.lower(), k.islower())))
```

Comment: You could just do `(k.lower(), k.islower())`

Comment: Actually using `key=str.lower` would be enough

Comment: @DeepSpace No if you want upper-case letters always first

Comment: @AndrejKesely OP specifically stated that `['a','A','b','d','t','z','Z']` is valid output

Comment: Could be easily changed (if that matters) to lower first by switching to `isupper()`

Comment: @DeepSpace `sorted(['z','t','Z','A','b','a','d'], key=str.lower)` produces `['A', 'a', 'b', 'd', 't', 'z', 'Z']`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Indeed, I guess that's a side-effect of `sorted` using a stable version of quicksort.

Comment: @AndrejKesely. I've explicitly addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)'s (or `list.sort`'s) extra keyword - `key`. You can pass to `key` a function according to which the sort will be performed. So for  example:

```py
l = ['z','t','Z','a','b','A','d']
print(sorted(l, key=str.lower))
```

Gives:

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'd', 't', 'z', 'Z']
```

**Note:** this will not preserve the order of lower/upper between different letters. It will preserve the order of original input.

Comment: Bonus: If you are defining a lambda just to call a function on the object that is passed in, you can just use the static version, in this case for example `(sorted(l, key=str.lower))`

Comment: @DeepSpace You are right. I wasn't sure if it can work here. I know that for example I could use just `int`, but since this is an instance method I wan't sure

Comment: @Tomerikoo. That's the beauty of methods in python. They are just regular functions that accept the instance as the first argument, and live in a class'es namespace. `str.lower(somestring)` produces identical results to `somestring.lower()`, if `somestring` is an instance of `str`.

Comment: Yep, played with it and got it better now. Thanks a lot for the point-out and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There are two options on how this sorting could be done. Option 1 is stable, meaning that the order of elements is preserved regardless of case:

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'] -> ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B']
```

The other option is to always put uppercase before or after lowercase:

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'] -> ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b'] or ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']
```

Both are possible with the `key` argument to `list.sort` (or the builtin `sorted`).

A stable sort is simply:

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'].sort(key=str.lower)
```

A fully ordered sort requires you to check the original status of the letter, in addition to comparing the lowercased values:

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'].sort(key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x.islower()))
```

This uses the fact that a tuples are compared lexicographically, or element-by-element. The first difference determines the order. If two letters have different values for `x.lower()`, they will be sorted as usual. If they have the same lowercase representation, `x.islower()` will be compared. Since uppercase letters will return 0 and lowercase letters return 1, lowercase letters will come after uppercase. To switch that, invert the sense of the comparison:

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'].sort(key=lambda x: (x.lower(), not x.islower()))
```

OR

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'].sort(key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x.isupper()))
```

OR

```
['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'].sort(key=lambda x: (x.lower(), -x.islower()))
```

etc...

Comment: This is exhausting answer, should be accepted by op!