# Sorting a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a list of strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)
>   [How do I sort unicode strings alphabetically in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097908/how-do-i-sort-unicode-strings-alphabetically-in-python)

I have a list of strings `list` and want to sort it alphabetically. When I call `list.sort()` the first part of the list contains the entries starting with upper case letters sorted alphabetically, the second part contains the sorted entries starting with a lower case letter. Like so:

```
Airplane
Boat
Car
Dog
apple
bicycle
cow
doctor
```

I googled for an answer but didn't came to a working algorithm. I read about the `locale` module and the `sort` parameters `cmp` and `key`. Often there was this `lambda` in a row with `sort`, which made things not better understandable for me.

How can I get from:

```
list = ['Dog', 'bicycle', 'cow', 'doctor', 'Car', 'Boat', 'apple', 'Airplane']
```

to:

```
Airplane
apple
bicycle
Boat
Car
cow
doctor
Dog
```

Characters of foreign languages should be taken into account (like ä, é, î).

Comment: Are you **sure** about the output you want? `Dog` seems to be at a very wrong place in that list.

Comment: @ecatmur this is not a duplicate of that question, this one is more about case-insensitivity than unicode

Comment: I think it *is* a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python though since the accepted answer on that question explains both locale-aware and non-locale-aware case insensitive comparisons using the same technique as in my answer.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: You're right. The accepted answer there solves my case. For `setlocale` on Windows you just have to specify something like `b'English_United States'` or `b'German_Germany'`.

Answer (score 10):

Use case-insensitive comparison:

```
>>> sorted(['Dog', 'bicycle', 'cow', 'doctor', 'Car', 'Boat',
        'apple', 'Airplane'], key=str.lower)
['Airplane', 'apple', 'bicycle', 'Boat', 'Car', 'cow', 'doctor', 'Dog']
```

This is actually the way suggested on the [python wiki about sorting](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/):

> Starting with Python 2.4, both list.sort() and sorted() added a key
>   parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element
>   prior to making comparisons.
>
> For example, here's a case-insensitive string comparison:
>
> ```
> >>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=str.lower)
> ['a', 'Andrew', 'from', 'is', 'string', 'test', 'This']
> ```

Comment: This places `Bär` after `Bor`.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a good overview of that topic here:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Scroll down about a page to here;

For example, here's a case-insensitive string comparison:

```
>>> sorted("This is a test string from Andrew".split(), key=str.lower)
```