# Sort strings into alphabetical order Python

Tags: python

So essentially what I'm doing is making a shipyard class that has the attribute "_containers" which is a singly linked list of container objects. Each container has the attribute "_destination" which is where it's going.

The shipyard._containers list has to be arranged alphabetically by destination. I know how to accomplish all of this except comparing the two destinations.

How can I compare two strings and figure out which one goes first based on alphabetical order? I'm not allowed to use any python lists at all.

Answer (score 3):

When `x` and `y` are variables naming Python objects that are strings,

x < y

is `True` if and only if `x` is alphabetically before `y`.

This may or may not match what **you** mean by "alphabetically before".  For example, all uppercase characters do come alphabetically before lowercase ones, so if `x='Zebra'` and `y='aardvark'`, `x < y` will be `True`.  To specifically ignore upper/lower case distinctions, use

```
x.lower() < y.lower()
```

More generally, Unicode can present several such traps, whereby code points that are in a certain order do **not** mean they must be compared in that order.  For a completely general approach to the Unicode Collation Algorithm, you can look at various alternatives discussed at [How do I sort unicode strings alphabetically in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097908/how-do-i-sort-unicode-strings-alphabetically-in-python) .

Answer (score 0):

```
containers = sorted(containers, key = lambda i: i.desitination)
```