# PyICU in python 3 error : ImportError: libicui18n.so.58

Tags: python, unicode, conda, pyicu

As I'm doing a project for non-english (Sinhala) language I need to sort the words in unicode.

So I followed answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097908/how-do-i-sort-unicode-strings-alphabetically-in-python/1318709#1318709) question and installed PyICU in a conda environment which I have already installed tensorflow and NLTK.

Now in python console (in Pycharm) when use `import icu` and execute the code I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pankaja/PycharmProjects/teamspark/testing/sinhalasort.py", line 1, in <module>
    import icu
  File "/home/pankaja/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/icu/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from _icu import *
ImportError: libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why is that ? Is there any possibility that `PyICU` can't be used in a conda environment ?

Comment: Have you installed the libicu? from the [project page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/) `Before building PyICU the ICU libraries must be built and installed`

Comment: How can I check for ICU library location ?

Comment: .so means Linux library - mostly created in C/C++ - so you may have to install it from Linux repository. Or you have to get source code in C/C++ and compile it.

Comment: @SiddharthDas Linux has command `find` to search files (using many useful optionos). There is also `locate` which use database with names of all files - so it can works faster, but you need to updated database (command `updatedb`) and it doesn't have options.

Answer (score 2):

Installing pyicu from the conda-forge channel can be achieved by adding conda-forge to your channels with:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Once the conda-forge channel has been enabled, pyicu can be installed with:

```
conda install pyicu
```

this solves the problem and it will install pyicu with dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libicu. On centos, just run

```
yum install libicu
```