# Wrong Hungarian (hu_HU) sort order

Tags: python, locale, strxfrm

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE,'hu_HU.ISO8859-2')
print(sorted(['c', 'á', 'b', 'z', 'é', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'Ő', 'Ű', 'ő', 'ű'], key=locale.strxfrm))
```

Expected: ['a', 'á', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'é', 'f', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Ű', 'ű', 'z']

Actual: ['a', 'á', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'é', 'f', 'z', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Ű', 'ű']

Note that 'z' is supposed to be the last letter.

I know my code "works" because it does put the 'á' and 'é' in the right place (and the "regular" sorted puts them after 'z'), so the bug I is in the locale definition.

I have MacOS Venture 13.6.4, python 3.11.7

How could I "update" the locale definitions? Is it something in the python or does it use the system locales?

Note: I tried to install PyICU and zope.ucol, but both failed during the installation, so don't tell me to use them.

Comment: Use PyICU, a [recommended solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097908/how-do-i-sort-unicode-strings-alphabetically-in-python) for this exact problem. If you have failed to install it, open a new question to solve the installation issue.

Comment: @Jeyekomon see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78114765/installing-pyicu-on-macos

Comment: Not sure Venture, but on all prior versions of macOS there isn't any Hungarian collation tables available, the Hungarian tables are symlinked to a generic system collation table. I have the same problem with a range of locales on macOS, and use PyICU for all sorting. In `/usr/share/locale/hu_HU.ISO8859-2` I see `LC_COLLATE -> ../la_LN.ISO8859-2/LC_COLLATE`

Comment: Maybe. It's a big mess. The hu_HU.UTF-8 doesn't work at all (even the 'á', 'é' are after z), ISO8859-2 partially, but I haven't even understand how, as my input is UTF-8 as far as I know.

Comment: @Gavriel the only way to sort using Hungarian collation correctly on macOS is to use PyICU.