# How to match a substring in a string, ignoring case

Tags: python, perl

I'm looking for ignore case string comparison in Python.

I tried with:

```
if line.find('mandy') >= 0:
```

but no success for ignore case. I need to find a set of words in a given text file. I am reading the file line by line. The word on a line can be *mandy*, *Mandy*, *MANDY*, etc. (I don't want to use `toupper`/`tolower`, etc.).

I'm looking for the Python equivalent of the Perl code below.

```
if ($line=~/^Mandy Pande:/i)
```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

If you don't want to use `str.lower()`, you can use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
import re

if re.search('mandy', 'Mandy Pande', re.IGNORECASE):
    # Is True
```

Comment: re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search
Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Comment: Be careful about special characters. They can cause problems with this method

Answer (score 45):

You are looking for the `.lower()` method:

```
string1 = "hi"
string2 = "HI"
if string1.lower() == string2.lower():
    print("Equals!")
else:
    print("Different!")
```

Btw, There's another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567/ignore-case-in-python-strings). Try looking at this.

Comment: No he's not. " [i don't want to use toupper/tolower etc.]"

Comment: i know, i read, but the re.match and re.search solutions don't check for special characters used in regex such as () or []

Comment: what have () or [] to do with the question?

Comment: This is not a more general answer, because tolower/toupper solutions are inappropriate for Unicode.

Comment: Let's call it a workaround then :) 5 years ago I wasn't as skilled as I am nowadays with English.

Comment: if you don't really need to avoid it (for some reason like unicode), maching with lower() can be much more efficient than regex match.

Answer (score 28):

One can use the `in` operator after applying [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) to both strings.

[`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) is the recommended method for use in case-insensitive comparison.

> Return a casefolded copy of the string. Casefolded strings may be used for caseless matching.
>
> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example, the German lowercase letter 'ß' is equivalent to "ss". Since it is already lowercase, lower() would do nothing to 'ß'; casefold() converts it to "ss".
>
> The casefolding algorithm is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard.
>
> New in version 3.3.

For case-insensitive substring search:

```
needle = "TEST"
haystack = "testing"
if needle.casefold() in haystack.casefold():
    print('Found needle in haystack')
```

For case-insensitive string comparison:

```
a = "test"
b = "TEST"
if a.casefold() == b.casefold():
    print('a and b are equal, ignoring case')
```

Comment: Also seems to support non-ANSI letters like the Danish/Norwegian Æ, Ø and Å.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
if haystackstr.lower().find(needlestr.lower()) != -1:
  # True
```

Answer (score 8):

```
a = "MandY"
a_low = a.lower()
if "mandy" in a_low:
    print("true")
```

work around

Answer (score 4):

you can also use: `s.lower() in str.lower()`

Comment: OP said "*I don't want to use toupper/tolower, etc.*"

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
if re.search('(?i)Mandy Pande:', line):
    ...
```

Comment: this doesn't check / match for control characters in for regexp like [] or () if i'm not wrong...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `in` operator in conjunction with `lower` method of strings.

`if "mandy" in line.lower():`

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.I).

```
In [14]: re.match("mandy", "MaNdY", re.IGNORECASE)
Out[14]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23a08b8>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a pandas series, you can mention **case=False** in the str.contains

```
data['Column_name'].str.contains('abcd', case=False)
```

OR if it is just two string comparisons try the other method below

You can use casefold() method. The casefold() method ignores cases when comparing.

```
firstString = "Hi EVERYONE"
secondString = "Hi everyone"

if firstString.casefold() == secondString.casefold():
    print('The strings are equal.')
else:
    print('The strings are not equal.')
```

Output:

```
The strings are equal.
```