# Python - "case insensitive" in a string or "case ignore"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, case-sensitive

I have a very simple problem. This is for a pandas dataframe ("df"). The answers are all more complex regarding string compare, which I have no use for. Here is the code that works for lowercase and returns only "apple":

```
df2 = df1['company_name'].str.contains(("apple"), na=False)
```

I need this to find "apple", "APPLE", "Apple", etc. Something like:

```
df2 = df1['company_name'].str.contains.caseignore((("apple"), na=False))
```

is there such a function anywhere?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "df" ? A panda dataframe ? If yes please edit your post to make this clear and add the "panda" tag, else explain what is this "df" thing.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579876/how-to-match-a-substring-in-a-string-ignoring-case

Comment: I'll do something like this: `df2 = df1['company_name'].str.upper().contains("ApPlE".upper())` and check everythoing uppercase.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) has a `case` parameter that is `True` by default. Set it to `False` to do a case insensitive match.

```
df2 = df1['company_name'].str.contains("apple", na=False, case=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the exact match and with strip the search on both sides with case ignore,

```
pd[pd['Asset Name'].str.strip().str.match('searchstring'.strip(),case=False)]
```