# Python - Ignore letter case

Tags: python

I have an if statement:

```
rules = input ("Would you like to read the instructions? ")
rulesa = "Yes"
if rules == rulesa:
    print  ("No cheating")
else: print ("Have fun!")
```

I wish for the user to be able to answer with Yes, YES, yES, yes or any other capitalisation, and for the code to know that they mean Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore case in Python strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567/ignore-case-in-python-strings)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/2433843

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this simple example you can just compare lowercased `rules` with `"yes"`:

```
rules = input ("Would you like to read the instructions? ")
rulesa = "yes"
if rules.lower() == rulesa:
    print  ("No cheating")
else: 
    print ("Have fun!")
```

It is OK for many cases, but be awared, some languages may give you a tricky results. For example, German letter `ß` gives following:

```
"ß".lower() is "ß"
"ß".upper() is "SS"
"ß".upper().lower() is "ss"
("ß".upper().lower() == "ß".lower()) is False
```

So we may have troubles, if our string was uppercased somewhere before our call to `lower()`.
Same behaviour may also be met in Greek language. Read the post 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/2433843 for more information.

So in generic case, you may need to use **`str.casefold()`** function (since python3.3), which handles tricky cases and **is recommended way for case-independent comparation**:

```
rules.casefold() == rulesa.casefold()
```

instead of just

```
rules.lower() == rulesa.lower()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
if rules.lower() == rulesa.lower():
```

This converts both strings to lower case before testing for equality.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to make the input upper or lower case, and compare with an upper or lower case word:

```
rulesa = 'yes'
if rules.lower() == rulesa:
   # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make either of uppercase comparison or lowercase comparison.

For Example:

```
rulesa.upper() == rules.upper()
```

or

```
rulesa.lower() == rules.lower()
```

both will give you output as **true**

Answer (score -2):

```
rules = raw_input("Would you like to read the instructions? ")
rulesa = "Yes"
if (rules == rulesa) or (rules.lower() == rulesa.lower()) or rules.upper() == rulesa.uppper():
   print  ("No cheating")
else: print ("Have fun!")
```

That will work everytime no matter the input and will keep the user's input as it was inputed! Have fun with it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `rules.upper() == rulesa.uppper()` after `(rules.lower() == rulesa.lower())`?

Comment: BTW `string.lower()` does not change the case of `string`.