# How to get every combination of a string?

Tags: python, string

For example if I have the word 'House', is there a way to get every possible version of it and set it to an array.

How it would look

```
word = 'House'
```

Function does something and the out put would look something like:

```
word = ['HOUSE', 'House, house', 'hoUse']
```

Comment: I'm curious why you'd ever want such a thing. This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). For example, are you trying to accept `yes`, `YES`, `Yes`, etc.?

Comment: Yes this is why.

Comment: Then take your input and use `.lower()` on it, then compare against `"yes"`.

Comment: How could this be used in an 'if' statement with an example?

Comment: Or [Ignore case in Python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62567/354577) or [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/354577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use binary combinations `01110`, `00011` etc. with [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get every combination of cases with a string. This means setting the 1's as uppercase and the 0's as lowercase. So `01110` -> `hOUSe`, `00011` -> `houSE` etc.

```
from itertools import product

def get_all_cases(string):
    return [
        "".join(
            letter.upper() if binary == 1 else letter
            for letter, binary in zip(string.lower(), binary_comb)
        )
        for binary_comb in product([0, 1], repeat=len(string))
    ]
```

Output:

```
>>> get_all_cases("House")
>>> ['house', 'housE', 'houSe', 'houSE', 'hoUse', 'hoUsE', 'hoUSe', 'hoUSE', 'hOuse', 'hOusE', 'hOuSe', 'hOuSE', 'hOUse', 'hOUsE', 'hOUSe', 'hOUSE', 'House', 'HousE', 'HouSe', 'HouSE', 'HoUse', 'HoUsE', 'HoUSe', 'HoUSE', 'HOuse', 'HOusE', 'HOuSe', 'HOuSE', 'HOUse', 'HOUsE', 'HOUSe', 'HOUSE']
```

You can also just map to `True` and `False` boolean values instead of `1` and `0`.

```
from itertools import product

def get_all_cases(string):
    return [
        "".join(
            letter.upper() if is_upper else letter
            for letter, is_upper in zip(string.lower(), comb)
        )
        for comb in product([False, True], repeat=len(string))
    ]
```

Comment: Just be warned: if the string is long this will generate a lot of combinations.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, 2^n where n is the length of string, to be exact. That being said, this is a slightly convoluted method of doing this. A better use of `itertools.product` is demonstrated in the duplicate question.

Comment: Great example of technically answering the question while ignoring the real problem.

Comment: @Chris Feel free to downvote if you don't like this answer.

Comment: Like I said, it technically answers the question. I prefer to let the question be deleted.